# How to add nodes under to different parents in Groovy Markup Builder by calling a method or closure

Tags: xml, groovy, builder, markupbuilder

I would like to produce below xml.
I do not want to add xsv block inside xpm and MyRoot by repeating the same code.Instead I want to call a method or closure so that It will return xsv block which can be added in the respective parent node(MyRoot and xpm)

```
<MyRoot>
   <xsv>
      <action>create</action>
      <actionID>4</actionID>
   </xsv>
   <xpm>
      <xsv>
         <action>create</action>
         <actionID>4</actionID>
      </xsv>
   </xpm>
</MyRoot>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following piece of code:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
def out = builder.MyRoot { 
   addXsv(builder, 'create', 4)
      xpm() {
         addXsv(builder, 'drop', 5)
      }
   }

def addXsv(builder, name, id) {
   builder.xsv() {
      action name
      actionID id
   }
}

println writer
```